# send a list of qml Items connect C++ class to QML :M16 error

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am going to send a list of qml Items to my c++ class, well I have used this tutorial https://ruedigergad.com/2011/11/13/exchange-data-and-objects-between-c-and-qml-and-vice-versa/

but there are some problem. Firstly lets look at my code

georefobject_.h

```
#ifndef GEOREFOBJECT_H
#define GEOREFOBJECT_H
#include "gcppoint_.h"
#include <qdebug.h>
class georefobject_ : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit georefobject_(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent){}

  Q_INVOKABLE void doA(gcppoint_ *a){
    qDebug() << "doing A: " << a->test();
  }

//  Q_INVOKABLE void doC(C *c){
//    qDebug() << "doing C: " << c->a()->test();
//  }

  Q_INVOKABLE void doAlist(QVariantList vl){
    qDebug() << "Doing AList... ";
    for(int i = 0; i < vl.size(); i++){
      qDebug() << "vl.at(" << i << "): " << vl.at(i);
      // Get the actual object out of a QVariant.
      gcppoint_ *a = qobject_cast<gcppoint_ *>(vl.at(i).value<QObject *>());
      qDebug() << "Data from A" << i << ": " << a->test();
    }
  }

  Q_INVOKABLE void doVl(QVariantList vl){
    qDebug() << "QVariantList passed as parameter.\nSize of vl: " << vl.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < vl.size(); i++){
      qDebug() << "vl.at(" << i << "): " << vl.at(i);
    }
  }

  Q_INVOKABLE gcppoint_* makeA(){
    gcppoint_* a = new gcppoint_();
    a->setTest("Another A");
    return a;
  }

  Q_INVOKABLE QVariantList makeAList(){
    QVariantList vl;

    gcppoint_* a1 = new gcppoint_();
    a1->setTest("newA1");
    vl.append(qVariantFromValue((QObject*)a1));

    gcppoint_* a2 = new gcppoint_();
    a2->setTest("newA2");
    vl.append(qVariantFromValue((QObject*)a2));

    return vl;
  }
};

#endif // GEOREFOBJECT_H
```

gcppoint_.h

```
#ifndef GCPPOINT_H
#define GCPPOINT_H
#include <QObject>
class gcppoint_ : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QString test READ test WRITE setTest NOTIFY testChanged)
public:
  explicit gcppoint_(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent){}

  QString test(){return myTest;}

  void setTest(QString t){
    myTest = t;
    testChanged(myTest);
  }

signals:
  void testChanged(QString t);

private:
  QString myTest;
};
#endif // GCPPOINT_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "gcppoint_.h"
#include "gcppointobject.h"
#include "georefobject_.h"
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <qquickitem.h>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QObject>
#include "gcppointobject.h"
#include "gcppoint_.h"
#include "georefobject_.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    //qmlRegisterType<gcppointobject>("gcppointobject", 1, 0, "gcppointobject");
    qmlRegisterType<georefobject_>("georefobject", 1, 0, "georefobject_");
    qmlRegisterType<gcppoint_>("gcppoint", 1, 0, "gcppoint_");


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));


    return app.exec();
}
```

and main.qml

```
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 as C2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
//import gcppointobject 1.0
import gcppoint 1.0
import georefobject 1.0
ApplicationWindow {

    gcppoint_{id: aa; test: "bar"}
   // gcppoint_{id: aaa; test: "blah"}
    georefobject{id: b}

}
```

I get two errors, the main error is in `georefobject_{id: b}` which says `invalid property name M16` but I think I have done every thing based on that tutorial,
Can some one help me with that?
thnaks

Comment: `georefobject_{id: b}` or `georefobject{id: b}`, is typo?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have tried both of them but none works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that name of the Items must be capitalized, and in your case it is not, the solution is for example:

```
qmlRegisterType<gcppoint_>("gcppoint", 1, 0, "Gcppoint_");
qmlRegisterType<gcppoint_>("georefobject", 1, 0, "Georefobject_");
```

And:

```
Gcppoint_{
    id: aa; test: "bar"
}
Georefobject_{id: b}
```

*Note:* See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-checking-code-syntax.html):

> M16   Error   Invalid property name name